# ansible 1.6 > using with_first_found in a with_items loop?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use `with_first_found` in a `with_items` loop such as:

```
- template:
    dest=/foo/{{ item.name }}-{{ item.branch | default('master') }}
    src={{ item }}
  with_first_found:
    - {{ item.name }}-{{ item.branch | default('master') }}
    - {{ item.name }}.j2
    - apache_site.j2
  with_items: apache_sites
```

Can't seem to make it work using `with_nested`.

Comment: Looks hairy, what are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 6):

Combining loops is unsupported, but you can use them as lookups:

```
vars:
  site_locations:
    - {{ item.name }}-{{ item.branch | default('master') }}
    - {{ item.name }}.j2
    - apache_site.j2

tasks:
    - template:
         dest=/foo/{{ item.name }}-{{ item.branch | default('master') }}
         src={{ lookup('first_found', site_locations }}
      with_items: apache_sites
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need for tc Server (tomcat). This is what I did:

1. I put the site-specific configuration in a separate tasks file (configure-sites.yml):

   ```
   - template:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: /foo/{{ apache_site.name }}-{{ apache_site.branch | default('master') }}
     with_first_found:
       - "{{ apache_site.name }}-{{ apache_site.branch | default('master') }}"
       - "{{ apache_site.name }}.j2"
       - apache_site.j2
   ```
2. From a separate tasks file I included that tasks file, passing it each site:

   ```
   - include: configure-sites.yml
     with_items: "{{ apache_sites }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: apache_site
   ```

This makes use of `loop_control` which requires Ansible 2.1+: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control

In case it helps, you can see exactly what I did here:
https://github.com/bmaupin/ansible-role-tcserver/blob/master/tasks/main.yml
https://github.com/bmaupin/ansible-role-tcserver/blob/master/tasks/configure-instances.yml